# Implement c++ visitor pattern avoiding circular dependency

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

I'm implementing a visitor pattern in C++ has described [here](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor/cpp/2). I have this file structure:

```
Base.h
---------------
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

#include "visitor.h"

class Base{
public: virtual void accept(const visitor& v)=0;
};

#endif

Derived.h
-----------------
#ifndef DERIVED_H
#define DERIVED_H

#include "base.h"
#include "visitor.h"

class Derived : Base {
public: virtual void accept(const visitor& v);
};

#endif

visitor.h
------------------
#ifndef VISITOR_H
#define VISITOR_H

#include "base.h"
#include "derived.h"

class visitor {
    void visit(const base& base);
    void visit(const derived& derived);
};

#endif
```

The cpp file only include the .h and define the acccept methods as described int the link above. The problem i have with these file structure is the circular dependency between headers. If i compile it with VS 2012 i get this error: Error C2504: Base class not defined. Thank you in advice and sorry for my bad english.

**Edit**:
I have changed my code as as follow:

```
Base.h
---------------
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

//#include "visitor.h"
class visitor;

class Base{
public: virtual void accept(const visitor& v)=0;
};

#endif

Derived.h
-----------------
#ifndef DERIVED_H
#define DERIVED_H

#include "base.h"
//#include "visitor.h"

class visitor;

class Derived : Base {
public: virtual void accept(const visitor& v);
};

#endif

visitor.h
------------------
#ifndef VISITOR_H
#define VISITOR_H

//#include "base.h"
//#include "derived.h"

class base;
class derived;

class visitor {
    void visit(const base& base);
    void visit(const derived& derived);
};

#endif
```

But now, on the cpp implementations (on base.cpp and derived.cpp) i get erorr c2872 'visitor' ambiguos symbol:

```
Base.cpp
---------
#include "base.h"
void base::accept(const visitor& v){ // on this line i get error c2872
   v.visit(this);
}

Derived.cpp
---------
#include "derived.h"
void derived::accept(const visitor& v){ // on this line i get error c2872
   v.visit(this);
}
```

Comment: Note that your `#ifndef VISITOR_H` in base.h should be `#ifndef BASE_H`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the `visitor.h` header file you don't need the includes, the compiler only need to know that the `base` and `derived` classes exists. This can easily be done by replacing the `#include` directives with the declarations of the classes:

```
class base;
class derived;
```

And in the other two header files you don't need the `visitor.h` include either, just replace that `#include` with

```
class visitor;
```

Comment: The key term here is "forward declaration."

Comment: I have done the changes you described but now, in the base.cpp and derived.cpp i get this error: error c2872 "visitor" ambiguos symbol on the line void base::accept(const visitor& v){}

Comment: You have not posted base.cpp and derived.cpp

Comment: @WileTheCoyot You of course need to include all relevant header files in the sources.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg please, could you make me a practial example? Thank you

Comment: @WileTheCoyot In the *source files* (`Base.cpp` and `Derived.cpp`) you need to include the `visitor.h` header file. This is because in the header files you are only telling the compiler that "there exists a class named `visitor`, but in the source file you are actually using instances of this class so the compiler needs the complete definition (and not only a declaration).